# What do you call a glossary accompanied with visuals?

Tags: vocabulary

I am trying to create a glossary but I want to incorporate some pictures but I'm pretty convinced that a glossary only contain words.

So what would you call a glossary with images where the images are related to the word being defined.

Comment: A "visual dictionary" http://www.visualdictionaryonline.com/

Comment: Are the images used to help illustrate word definitions, which are the only glossary entries, or are there entries that are themselves images? Not clear. If the former, then it is just a glossary (with illustrations). What makes you "*pretty convinced that a glossary only contain[s] words*"? That's false, if you meant the former, at least.

Comment: @mika http://www.amazon.com/Merriam-Websters-Visual-Dictionary-Claude-Corbeil/dp/0877791511/ref=dp_ob_title_bk; https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=visual+dictionary&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=5&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cvisual%20dictionary%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stressing that earlier answers offer suggestions ('illustrated glossary' and 'visual glossary') that may more closely fit your needs, as expressed in your question, I'll offer you a third choice:

> pictorial glossary

Species of glossary hybridize readily, so the three types on offer are not always or altogether different:

An **illustrated glossary** presents a verbal explanation of a term along with illustrations. The illustrations may be direct illustrations of the meanings of the terms explained, illustrations of secondary or tertiary terms directly or indirectly involved in the explanations, or illustrations peripherally or not at all involved with the explanations of the terms. This, the **illustrated glossary**, is the broadest, most inclusive type of graphical glossary, and offers the most latitude for composing, choosing, and providing illustrations.

A **visual glossary** may, at one extreme, be entirely composed of graphical illustrations, with no words involved at all. At the opposite extreme, the illustrations accompanying the explanations of terms are directly related to the terms explained, and the illustrations are (usually) the primary focus of the explanations of terms. Indirect connections between the illustrations and the terms explained are unlikely.

A **pictorial glossary** may be considered a subtype of both the illustrated and the visual glossary. The difference is that a pictorial glossary presents an explanation of a term either entirely by means of, or with accompanying, *pictures*. Broadly speaking this will exclude, for example, graphs and charts, equations, or any other type of illustrative material that is not a picture.

As a subtype of the **illustrated** and **visual** glossary species, **pictorial glossary** is the narrowest, most restricted type of glossary that might answer: it would only be appropriate if all of the illustrations in the glossary were pictures.

Answer (score 4):

I'd call it an ***[illustrated](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/illustrated) glossary***:

> - (a text) provided with explanatory or decorative images: *illustrated with colorful drawings.*

The Free Dictionary

*Mosses and Other Bryophytes: [An illustrated glossary](https://books.google.it/books?id=qkFFAQAAIAAJ&q=%22illustrated%20glossary%22&dq=%22illustrated%20glossary%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0CCUQ6AEwAWoVChMImuj-0Kv_yAIVRhYPCh0-wgZW):*

> - The second edition has half again ***as many pages (over 330) and illustrations (nearly 1400)*** as the first edition did, and two-thirds of those illustrations are new. Over 530 species of bryophytes are illustrated.

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=illustrated%20glossary&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cillustrated%20glossary%3B%2Cc0): *illustrated glossary*.

Example of illustrated architectural glossary:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Consider, ***visual glossary***.

> [Multi-language visual
>   glossary](https://books.google.fr/books?id=MciabtqZUR0C&dq=%22visual+glossary%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAmoVChMI2IvY6Kv_yAIVScAUCh1DQgOT)

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=visual+glossary&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cvisual%20glossary%3B%2Cc0)